# Ember handle save action and extract pressed key

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a textarea from which I want to catch a `shift-enter` event, which is pressed inside it.

`enter` as well as `shift-enter` both call the `save` method of the `controller`. But inside the `save` method, I don't seem to have an `param` giving me the pressed key(number).

When I implement the `keyUp: (e) ->` method inside my `view(controller)`, it either not called when the `save` method is implemented inside the `controller`, or, when the `save` method is not implemented, I get an error saying `nothing handled the action save`.

Actually I only want to know if the pressed key(s), which called the `save` action was either `enter` or `shift-enter`.

What's the best way to do this? Thanks!

**Update**

My code looks like this now:

```
ContactIndex = Ember.View.extend
  listenKey: ((event) ->
    if(event.which == 13)
      @get('controller').send('save', event.shiftKey)
  ).on('keyDown') # When I use `keyUp` instead, the isShift boolean value is not being transmitted.


Contact = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  save: (isShift) ->
    console.log('Shift Key Pressed: ' + isShift)
    false
```

Every time I press `enter` or `shift-enter`, the `save action` gets called twice.

Comment: Can you create a jsbin duplicating your problem ?

Comment: I updated the question with code @lame_coder

Answer (score 2):

its better to pass a boolean value whether its a shift key event or not from the view to controller.

```
App.IndexController=Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function(isShift){
      console.log('Shift Key Pressed: ' + isShift);
      return false;
    }
  }
});

App.IndexView=Ember.View.extend({
  listenKey: function(event){
    if(event.which===13){
      this.get('controller').send('save',event.shiftKey);
    }
  }.on('keyUp')
});
```

Check this jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fazibu/1/edit

Comment: `event.shiftKey` from `this.get('controller').send('save',event.shiftKey);` is not being transferred to the controller's `save` action. `isShift` in the controller always has the value of the text inside the textarea.

Comment: i think you may have provided action in templates..remove that..`listenKey` method will take care of that...

Comment: Yes I looked at the jsbin. Ok, I've got it working so far that the shift key is being recognized but when I press `shift-enter`, the `save` action in being called twice, once with and once without `shiftKey = true`.

Comment: Could there be a difference when using a textarea instead of a textfield? @CodeJack

Comment: i dont think so..its called only once here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fazibu/2/edit